# spring don't debug- Module named 'BackOfficeEar' failed to redeploy. See Error Log view for more detail

Tags: java, spring, debugging, weblogic, mybatis

I'm trying to debug my spring java code, and got this error:

```
Module named 'BackOfficeEar' failed to redeploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
```

when I run it it's working fine. but with debugger I got the error and can't debug my code.
What can I do?

This is my error-log:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named 'BackOfficeEar' failed to redeploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.redeploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1029)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1522)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:945)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:736)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Contains: Module named 'BackOfficeEar' failed to redeploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
Contains: Module named 'BackOfficeEar' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
Contains: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '/Mobile' is already in use by the module: Mobile application: BackOfficeEar
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:193)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:532)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.redeploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:897)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.redeploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:866)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.redeploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:959)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1522)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:945)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:736)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
```

I have two folders inside workspace, 1.backOffice - the project that I'm writing my code inside.
2. backOfficeEar- the project that the weblogic debug.

Thank you!

Comment: Share the entire Error Log

Comment: updated my question. Thank you!